# 413 Request Entity Too Large in Comfortable Mexican Sofa

Tags: ruby-on-rails, comfortable-mexican-sofa

While uploading a pdf file to the files section of Comfortable Mexican Sofa that is 2.8Mb in size I keep getting a "413 - Request Entity is too large" error.  Is there a max file size allowed to be uploaded?  Is there a way to increase this limit?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has something to do with webserver configuration. For example, in Apache you have this setting: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestbody

Error you're getting has nothing to do with Rails or CMS.